# How to log RequestBody in async spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, spring-reactive

I added an async endpoint to a existing `spring-mvc` application:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping("/")
    public Mono<String> post(Object body) {
       return Mono.just("test");
       //webClient.retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
    }
}
```

I want to create a global interceptor/filter that will log the request body payload. But how can I get access to it?

I tried adding a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`, but the payload is always empty:

```
static class LoggingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
            ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
            byte[] buf = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
            System.out.println(buf);
            System.out.println(buf.length);

            return true;
        }
}
```

Maybe the payload is not yet present in the request, or has already been read. So how can I access the body in this async case?

Comment: use `IOUtils.toString(request.getReader())` get the request body content,but I don't know what different between our codes?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in **Webflux** you cannot use *HandlerInterceptorAdapter* because it came from **web mvc** module and works only with the servlets.
I found a good article with [solutions](https://piotrminkowski.com/2019/10/15/reactive-logging-with-spring-webflux-and-logstash/).

P.S. You must to remove spring-mvc dependencies if going to use reactive endpoins.

Comment: I have to keep spring-mvc unfortunately.

Comment: So,for async endpoints in web mvc use @Async annotation without webflux

Comment: Ok that would work, but in my real world app I return a `Mono<String>` coming directly from `webClient` call, so I have to return a Mono here (or use `.block()` on the webclient, which is not good).

Comment: I understand, but you shouldn’t mix webflux and webmvc, these are absolutely different paradigms, use RestTemplate instead of webclient for webmvc application.

Comment: dont use RestTemplate, it is deprecated. You should use WebClient, if you wish to use WebClient like RestTemplate, you call block() and it will act the same way As restTemplate.

Comment: Blocking is bad in a full webflux application if you have a rest endpoint that returns a Mono/Flux to the calling client, then it is bad to block. And a reactive application is not a necessarily "async". So saying "Async spring controller" is wrong. A reactive application can be "synchronous" if the application feels that the request should be processed in sync.